# VBA that imports data meeting certain criteria from all spreadsheets in a directory

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

This the following code that I have:

```
Public Function Import_Multi_Excel_Files()

Dim InputFile As String
Dim InputPath As String

InputPath = "L:\Directory\To\Project\Data\"
InputFile = Dir(InputPath & "*.xls*")
worksheetName = "WorksheetThatHasData!A:H"

Do While InputFile <> ""
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "Table_1", InputPath & InputFile, -1, worksheetName, True '< The true is for column headers
    InputFile = Dir
Loop

End Function
```

The above code is grabbing all of the data from a specific worksheet within each workbook (which is good) and importing it into MS Access.  But I noticed that our reports always include the current month and previous month even though the report is dated for the current month.  Every file name has the format Report - YYYYMM.  The idea I'm kicking around is something that will look at the YYYYMM portion of the file name and only grab the data with that corresponding date.

**Edits and Additions Below**

Actuarial_Report-201705
Enrollment_Report-201705
Premium-Data-201705

Each of the above reports includes information from May AND April.  But the previous months report will clearly include data from April but also March, and so on.  What's happening is that all the data I've imported counted enrollment, premium, and actuarial info twice.  I want to only pull 201705 data from the 201705 reports and have the code ignore the 201704 info.

Comment: Please supply some sample file names (+ extension). Also, make your question more explicit. What exactly do you want to do after isolating month and year?

Comment: The idea you are kicking around is a good one. Post the code you tried so far to implement that idea, together with a brief description of where you are stuck and the faulty behaviour (e.g. error message).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  I've added my question towards the bottom.  If the report has the date 201705 in the file name, I only want the information from 2017-05 copied.  The file names all have dates of the form YYYYMM and within the workbook, column B has the date in the form YYYY-MM.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Alternatively, a separate piece of code that modifies the reports and deletes the months which are not meant to be in the report (delete every row with 2017-04 in 2017-05).

Comment: Please include the extensions like I asked. I will need to know if it's an `xls` or an `xlsx` file.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth xslx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `While` loop with the following:

```
Dim strMonth As String
Dim strYear As String
Do While InputFile <> ""
    strMonth = Mid(InputFile, Len(InputFile) - 6, 2)
    strYear = Mid(InputFile, Len(InputFile) - 10, 4)
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "Table_1", InputPath & InputFile, -1, worksheetName, True '< The true is for column headers
    CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * From Table_1 WHERE MyDateColumn < #" & strYear & "/" & strMonth & "/01#"
    InputFile = Dir
Loop
```

Where `MyDateColumn` is the column where you store dates.

**Assumptions:** You are not storing any other old information in `Table_1` that you want to keep, else you would want to import to another table, remove the invalid date info, and then  append the data to `Table_1`

The end of the file name cannot change, else this will generate bugs.

Note that I'm not using parameters in my query, but since the string is from a filename and has a max length of 6 with a `/` in the middle, the risk of SQL injection is not present.

Comment: All of your assumptions are correct.  The purpose of this database is to consolidate a bunch of separate pieces of information into one report.  I've only recently started sticking my toes into the water of vba since we are getting busier and reports are being demanded more often.

Comment: I just ran it.  It appears to still be doubling the numbers.

Comment: Doubling numbers? It's supposed to remove dates before a certain date. I know nothing of doubling numbers. Provide an exact table structure of the table you're importing to.

Comment: The worksheet is pretty simple:  Name, Date, Amount.  What I'm doing is looking at the 201705 and 201704 file.  It still doubled the totals for 2017-04.  So it's still counting the  dates twice.

Comment: EXACT table structure please, including field type, of the Access table, not the excel sheet

Comment: Just to test, I've truncated the range I wanted it to pull (just three columns).  So my access table is as follows Column Name (Type):

Group ID (Short Text), Paid Date (Date/Time), and Paid Claims (Currency).

Comment: And you have replaced the date field in my code correctly? Can you step through it and make sure it's deleting the invalid data?

Comment: Yes.  Just pasted it in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153395/discussion-between-erik-von-asmuth-and-emka).